# Does a high content in salt extend the refrigerated shelf life of cooked meat?

Tags: storage-lifetime

I cook usually 1kg block at 65°C for 6 hours with 40g (4%) of salt, 10g (1%) of sugar, and a good amount of white and black pepper.

After cooking it, I cool it in an ice bath, then I store it in the fridge; first, one day uncovered, so it dries out a bit, and then in a Tupperware.

My question is: would this high content of salt increase the shelf life over the normal 3-4 days of a roast?

ADMINS: I am well aware of this [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer). What I want to know is if making a dish salted would extend its shelf life, and if not, what would be the alternatives. If you don't have the answer, please leave the question open. Maybe someone else would have.

Comment: You really haven't changed the question from your previous attempt.  Food preservation requires multiple hurdles to be exceeded.  Simply adding more salt to the cook step is certainly helpful, but you have not followed a food preservation procedure that would extend shelf life.

Comment: >  Simply adding more salt to the cook step is certainly helpful, but you have not followed a food preservation procedure that would extend shelf life

Could you explain this a bit further, or let the question open so someone else has the opportunity to do so? @moscafj

Comment: @Daniel I wrote this in a comment to your older question: your food does not fall into the category of "preserved" by just adding salt. You either get a book on charcuterie and follow a recipe for salami, pökelfleisch, or whatever you fancy from there, or you follow the table for "cooked protein" in the linked question. It is not that we do not know of alternatives, it is that such alternatives do not exist. Food preservation is a well-researched subject with very firm rules.

Comment: And just for clarification: The fact that one or multiple attempts didn’t give you food poisoning after the safe time frame doesn’t mean you have a safe process. It’s still unsafe, note that no longer safe doesn’t equal spoiled. You need _significantly more_ salt plus an established procedure to make the meat “safe” by food safety standards.

Comment: > You either get a book on charcuterie. On the other hand, how convenient would it be to be able to find the information on the Internet. You know... Maybe from a community dedicated to cooking advice? Sometimes I have weird ideas... @rumtscho

Comment: @Daniel If you want a recipe for making salami, yes, you can find it on the Internet too, with the caveat that there it is a bit harder to distinguish between reliable and not reliable sources. Our site does not accept recipe requests as questions, our stronger side is when you have a recipe and run into trouble executing it.